# Git GUI push to specific refs namespace

Tags: git, gerrit, git-gui

In my git config I have `remote.origin.push` set to `refs/heads/*:refs/for/*`. A CLI push of `git push origin master` is effectively equivalent to `git push origin master:refs/for/master`.

Doing a push through Git Gui doesn't achieve the same thing. It seems like what's in the business logic is something like `git push origin master:refs/heads/master`. Is there a way to make Git Gui push to the `refs/for` namespace?

Here is how the Git Gui push window looks like:

[image: Git GUI]

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar [discussion in 2013](http://lists-archives.com/git/806536-git-gui-modify-push-dialog-to-support-gerrit-review.html) for supporting gerrit pusges from git-gui

> In my gerrit repos, I have this configuration
>
> ```
> $  git config remote.origin.push HEAD:refs/for/master
> ```
>
> And so I can simply '`git push`' and git does what I mean.
>
> My main complaint with git-gui's push is that it ignores my configuration.
> Can you teach git-gui to honor this setting, instead?

However, it does not seem to have been implemented.